# Will Google's Drive API deprecation affect Online Accounts?

Tags: online-accounts, google-drive

Google is deprecating older Drive APIs. See the announcement from Google. (https://9to5google.com/2020/06/29/old-g-suite-apps/) Is the Online Accounts function going to be affected?